# Google Glass goes inactive after ten seconds of use

Tags: google-glass

Actually, this is not a question. Just wanted to help other Glass developers if they are running into a similar problem.

I just received my Glass a few days ago. It is running XE17.2. It had two problems. 1) It would shut down in 10 or 20 seconds of use and 2) it would get hot quickly.

I was on call with Google tech support. It turns out there is a problem with head calibration algorithm in the current code. It would simply make Glass inactive on even a slight motion of the head. Moreover, while it is in inactive state, it is still running the calibration algorithm, making the hardware hot.

With the technician's help, I managed to quickly navigate and disable head calibration before it would turn off.  Now, both the problems are solved. The tech guy says they will fix this problem in their next software update. Regards.

Comment: I would suggest two things: 1) rewriting this as a question. Then writing an answer to it. 2) this question as is, is off-topic on StackOverflow however because it's not strictly about programming, it appears as though http://android.stackexchange.com/ does accept Google Glass questions.

Comment: How to disable head calibration?